# can't find questions by category name in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

i am trying to retrieve questions based on the category witch they belong with this function inside my questions controller:

```php
public function getByCategoryName($categoryName) {
        $category = Category::where('name', $categoryName)->first();
        return response($category->questions);

    }
```

the problem is that, even if `$category` its being correctly set, `$questions` is null and the browsers returns an empty response to my request

the tables are created like this:

Questions table:

```php
        Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('title')->nullable(false);
            $table->string('content')->nullable(false);
            $table->integer('points')->default(0);
            $table->foreignId('user_id')
                ->constrained('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->string('category_name');
            $table->foreign('category_name')
                ->references('name')->on('categories')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate(null);

        });
```

categorie table:

```php
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('name')->nullable(false);
            $table->unique('name');
        });
```

I have the relatives relationship functions HasMany and BelongsTo seated inside the the models.

Question model:

```php
public function category(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
```

Category model:

```php
public function question() : HasMany {
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please share model codes also.

Comment: Did you define a relationship `public function questions()` on `Category.php` model? If you didn't, `$category->questions` is going to be `null`.

Comment: yes I did, I've not included it not to overload the question with code, I'll  do it now

Comment: Also, why are you linking `questions` and `categories` on `category_name`? Use `category_id` for proper relational database mapping.

Comment: *"overload the question with code"* - That only really matters for irrelevant code. If your question is about why `$category->questions` is not working, I think including the definition in the Model(s) is important and relevant, especially if you're not using `category_id` as the linking column...

Comment: about that, is it really a bad thing? Wouldn't it be easier if they were linked via the category name?, that way when I create a new question I have to include the category name and not the id

Comment: Yeah, primary ids (`categories.id`) and using that as a FK (`questions.category_id`) is much better performance-wise. Text columns aren't well indexed by default, while primary auto-incrementing ones _are_. Also, in my experience, it's not easier in the long run. You might be able to do `Question::where('category_name', 'Test')->get()` to get all Questions for the `Test` Category, but it's also just as easy to do `Category::where('name', 'Test')->first()->questions`, and even easier if you just use the ID: `Question::where('category_id', 1)->get()` or `Category::find(1)->questions`, etc.

Comment: Also, your issue is `public function question()` (singular) vs using it as `$category->questions` (plural). `->question` is `null`, `->questions` is a `hasMany()`, but will still fail. You need to update it to `public function questions() { return $this->hasMany(Question::class, 'category_name'); }` for it to work as written.

Comment: thanks for the help but now it returns an empty array even if in my db are questions with that category

Comment: Right, as it would, as you're not using `id` and `category_id`:. Read the docs on how to set `name` and `category_name` as the linking columns: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many: `public function questions() { return $this->hasMany(Question::class, 'category_name', 'name'); }`

Comment: thanks for helping out and giving some resources

Comment: No problem! Sidenote, if you had used `categories.id` and `questions.category_id`, this would have worked as just `public function questions() { return $this->hasMany(Question::class); }`, which should be another reason to use `id` instead of `name` 

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out. It's better to use the primary ID key for efficient mapping. However, for education purposes it is possible and I will explain. Eloquent determines the foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with _id.
So, in this case, Eloquent assumes that the Question model has a category_id column.
However, since the foreign key on the Question model is not category_id, we must pass a custom key name as the second argument to the belongsTo method:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'foreign_key'); // If we do not pass this eloquent thinks the foreign key is 'category_id'
}

// We need to pass our custom foreign key
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_name');
}
```

Eloquent assumes the parent model Category will be associated using its primary id. Since this is not our case we need to associate the parent model key to the 'name' column.
So we need to pass a third argument to the belongsTo method specifying the parent tables custom key:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_name', 'name');
}
```

Your complete solution should look something like this.

```
// Question model
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_name', 'name');
}

// Category model
public function questions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Question::class, 'category_name', 'name');
}
```

Comment: @TimLewis first time i did something correctly just by not reading documentation :) never thought it could be relationship method name, always have been class name

Answer (score -1):

Change this :

```
    public function question() : HasMany {
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
    }
```

To this :

```
    public function questions() : HasMany {
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class, 'category_name');
    }
```

Comment: For questions where it's a simple syntax error, please don't post answers, especially if they've been posted in the comments already. There is a `Close Question` reason for typos, which is why I didn't post my comment as an answer.

Comment: It wasn't only a typo, there's also a specification of foreign key.

Comment: Which is clearly documented: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many.

Comment: Most of things here are documented, i don't see any reason not providing an answer. Just trying to help here. Plus formatting in comments is not ideal to write an answer which basically replaces the whole relationship method.

Comment: I know, but if they had read the documentation and followed it in the first place, this wouldn't have been a question to begin with. I appreciate you trying to help, but answering questions that fit into a clear close reason (as this one does, it's a syntax issue, not necessarily just a "typo") isn't the best idea on Stackoverflow.